# Understanding this bubble sort solution in Prolog

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, prolog, bubble-sort

How does this bubble sort solution work in Prolog?

```
bubblesort([], []).
bubblesort([H], [H]).
bubblesort([H|D], R) :-
    bubblesort(D, E),
    [B|G] = E,
    (  (H =< B, R = [H|E])
    ;  (H > B,  bubblesort([B,H|G], R))
    ).
```

Here is an example trace: https://pastebin.com/T0DLsmAV

I understand the the line bubblesort(D,E), is responsible for sorting it down to one element, but I don't understand how this works. I understand the basics of lists in prolog, but still cannot work out how this solution operates.

Comment: any feedback? did any of the answers help, at all?

Answer (score 2):

The main difficulty with this code is that bad variable names were chosen and are making the logic harder to follow than it needs to be.

The first two cases are obviously base cases. The first says "the empty list is already sorted" and the second says "a singleton list is already sorted." This should make sense. The third case is where things get interesting.

Let's examine the first part.

```
bubblesort([H|D], R) :-
    bubblesort(D, E),
```

All that's happened so far is we've named our result `R` and broken our inputs into a first element `H` and a tail `D`. From there, we have said, let's bubblesort the tail of our input and call that `E`. Maybe this would be a little easier to follow?

```
bubblesort([H|T], Result) :-
    bubblesort(T, TSorted),
```

Next up,

```
    [B|G] = E,
```

Again, bad names, but what the author is intending to do here is straightforward: take apart the result of sorting the tail so we can talk about whether the next item in the sorted tail is the right element for that position, or if it needs to switch places with the head of our input. Let's rename:

```
    [HeadOfTSorted|RestOfTSorted] = TSorted,
```

Now we have a condition. Think of it in terms of prepending onto a sorted list. Say you have some element, like 3, and I hand you a sorted list. You want to determine if your 3 goes at the front or somewhere else. Well, suppose I gave you a sorted list that looked like [5,7,19,23,...]. You'd know that your 3 is right where it needs to be, and you'd hand back [3,5,7,19,23,...]. That's exactly the first case of the condition:

```
    (  (H =< HeadOfTSorted, Result = [H|TSorted])
```

Now consider another case, where I hand you a list that starts with [1,2,...]. You know you can't just put the three at the start and give me back [3,1,2,...]. But you don't really know where the 3 goes; it just doesn't go at the start. So what you have to do is *resort* the rest of the list with the 3 at the start, after the 1: `[1 | resorted([3,2,...])]`. That's effectively the other branch of the condition:

```
    ;  (H > HeadOfTSorted,  bubblesort([HeadOfTSorted,H|RestOfTSorted], R))
    ).
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I renamed them just so I could follow the code. Even one-letter names can be suggestive: H, T (for the usual [H|T]), S ("sorted") instead of R, eliminate the E, replace [B|G] with [M|R] ("minimal"; "rest"). then it was readable. Maybe they made sense in some other language (as in, not English -- besides, short var names should always be commented at their introduction with the full intended name, @ OP). I'm not so sure it's a bubble sort though. :)

Comment: @WillNess I agree, I think this is insertion sort.

Comment: I suspect it's worse than that. Insertion sort inserts by a special, efficient, step. This algo re-does whole lot of effort, it looks like.

Comment: @WillNess Probably, but all of the N^2 sorts redo a lot of effort. Of course in the literature they're talking about arrays with random access and O(1) swaps, which isn't our life with linked lists.

Comment: well, I had to check it, now. :) [turned out](https://ideone.com/eVTyK1) it's n^3, vs. 'true' bubble sort's n^2.1, empirically.

Answer (score 1):

*note:* the key to recursive problem solving is exactly *not* to think about the minutiae of our code's operations. Imagine you *already have* the solution, then just use it to solve a smaller subproblem, thus arriving at the full problem's solution.

---

Your code, with more suggestive variable names so I could follow it, reads:

```erlang
bubblesort([], []).          % empty list is already sorted

bubblesort([H], [H]).        % singleton list is already sorted

bubblesort([H|T], S) :-      % `[H|T]` sorted is `S`,   *if*
    bubblesort(T, [M|R]),    %    `T` sorted is `[M|R]`,    *and*
    (                                 %   *either*,
       H =< M,                        %     in case `H` is not greater than `M`, 
             S = [H,M|R]              %       `S` is `[H,M|R]`,    
    ;                                 %   *or*
       H > M,                         %     in case `H` is greater than `M`,
             bubblesort([M,H|R], S)   %       `S` is `[M,H|R]` sorted by the same algorithm
    ).
```

(`H` is for "head", `T` is for "tail", `S` is "sorted", `R` "rest" and `M` is "minimum" -- see below for that).

We prove its correctness by [structural induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction). The induction hypothesis (**IH**) is that this definition is correct for shorter lists. We need to prove it is then also correct for a longer list. Indeed `T` is one-element shorter than `[H|T]`. Thus **IH** says `[M|R]` is sorted. This means `M` is the minimum element in `T`. It also means `T` is non-empty (sorting doesn't change the number of elements), so the clauses are indeed mutually-exclusive.

If `H` is not larger than the minimum element in `T`, `[H,M|R]` is obviously sorted.

Otherwise, we sort `[M,H|R]`. `M` is the minimum element and thus guaranteed to be the first in the result. What's actually sorted is `[H|R]`, which is one element shorter, thus by **IH** sorting it works. **QED**.

If the last step sounds fishy to you, consider replacing the second alternative with the equivalent

```erlang
    ;   H > M,                        %     in case `H` is greater then `M`,
             bubblesort([H|R], S1),   %       `S1` is `[H|R]` sorted by the same algorithm
                        S = [M|S1] 
    ).
```

where the applicability of the induction step is even clearer.

I'm not so sure it's a [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) though.

---

*update:* Indeed, [measuring](https://ideone.com/eVTyK1) the [empirical orders of growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth), its number of inferences grows as *~ n<sup>3</sup>* (or slower), but true bubble sort clocked at *~ n<sup>2.1</sup>* (close enough to the theoretical *~ n<sup>2</sup>*), where *n* is the list's length:

```erlang
tbs([], []).               % 'true' bubble sort
tbs([H],[H]).
tbs(L,S):- bubble(L,B),
           ( L==B -> S=L ; tbs(B,S) ).

bubble([],[]).
bubble([A],[A]).
bubble([A,B|C],R):- 
  (  A =< B -> bubble([B|C],X), R=[A|X]
  ;            bubble([A|C],X), R=[B|X] ).
```

Comment: I had rather [the more common](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20079763/772868) formulation in mind: That is, take (a single) swap only if there is a need to do so.

Comment: ah yes, that code is more Prologish than what I wrote... `swap` there is `bubble` here, more or less. I guess I translated the Wikipedia description in more direct, value-oriented way (i.e., "functional"). Instead of producing a Boolean indicator, in Prolog failure or success in itself is an indicator. --- the complexity should be the same.

Comment: Yours should be somehow better: in each iteration you swap possibily more than one pair

Comment: ... but: you have to perform `==` which compares again the lists up to the point were they are different...

Comment: um, sorry, the linked algo is not bubble sort. the bubble must continue going through the list. there can be several swaps along the way, IIRC the Wikipedia. ---- I could produce a Boolean indicator, but it won't change the complexity. The `==` just doubles the list traverses, at the most (I think?).

Comment: That program is from Bratko.  But I agree, however, nor is yours! You are unnecessarily revisiting the entire list. But after each visit, you could forget the last element.

Comment: (it's still a bubble sort BTW, just unoptimized, according to Wikipedia...)